# How to write "write" function without effecting inherited class in Odoo 8?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, openerp-8

The situation is as follows:

This is my .py file

```
class mom_meeting(osv.osv):

    _name = "mom.meeting"
    _rec_name = 'meet_ref'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']
```

and I had added the mail followers or openchatter in my custom module, now when I tried writing a "write" function as follows:

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
         user_ids = []
         sobj = self.pool.get('mom.meeting').browse(cr, uid, ids, context=None)
             if rec.ch_prsn.user_id.id == uid or rec.min_prp.id == uid:
                 return super(mom_meeting, self).write(cr, uid, [rec.id], vals, context=None)
             else:
                 raise osv.except_osv('Error', 'You dont have access right to edit this record, Please click Discard to revert changes')
```

Its not allowing any other user to send a message in openchatter. Any help/suggestion would be really great. Thanks!

Comment: I am not getting the purpose what you want to achieve with that code ? There is no meaning of for loop here because you have added return and raise statement in if - else so any one of the statement will break this loop.

Comment: Emipro Technologies, Sorry , My bad, made the code changes. The point is, I have added such conditions like except two persons defined in the field 'ch_prsn' and 'min_prp' should not be able to edit the record that is 'mom.meeting'

Comment: But since I have added openchatter(email.thread), it causes the same raise error while sending a message  using "send a message " in openchatter for other users .

Comment: You can create group for those users to whom you want to allow access of that model and for that group just define access rights in csv file none other than those group's user will be accessed that model.

Comment: Emipro technologies., Its not applicable, as the value in those fields 'ch_prsn' and 'min_prp' will vary , and those users cant be put in a group.

Comment: Anyone with any suggestion on this..?

Comment: Sharma, How and where to use SUPERUSERID,

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate need of calling super method, you can use like this:-

instead of this ->

```
super(mom_meeting, self).write(cr, uid, [rec.id], vals, context=None)
```

you can give-> `osv.osv.write(cr, uid, [rec.id], vals, context=None)`

This will call directly write function of ORM...

Hope this helps....

Comment: Baiju KS, I have tried this, its still the same. ;(